# Convert number to scientific notation and obtain exponent flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I convert a number to scientific notation and obtain the exponent? For example if I have 0.000000001 and want to convert it to 1e-9

Comment: Just found out a better way to do it. Check my answer edit

Comment: @dm_tr can you help me to get this "1.1369E-10" this kind of number. or can you tell me is it possible by method or i have to write method to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and try it as following

```
final value = 0.000000025;
String res = NumberFormat.scientificPattern(Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode).format(value);
print("Formatted value is $res");
```

**EDIT**
A better and cleaner approach, which does not require any additional package, is the method `toStringAsExponential()`. Here is how to use it

```
final value = 0.000000025;
print(value.toStringAsExponential());
```